# Difference between Django `BaseCommand` loggers and `logging.getLogger()`

Tags: python, django, logging

When writing custom Django management commands, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) recommend using `self.stdout` and `self.stderr`.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("Hello world!")
        self.stderr.write("Something went horribly wrong")
```

I've typically used the `logging` module in the past:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        logging.info("Hello world!")
        logging.error("Something went horribly wrong")
```

A few questions:

- Is there a difference between the Django `BaseCommand` loggers and the `logging` logger?
- Does the Django `BaseCommand` logger use the `logging` module under the hood? If so, what level does `self.stdout` and `self.stderr` use?

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` are just output handlers. These log by default to the console, but can for example with I/O redirection or a pipe pass the input to a file, device, or another process.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you know which log level they use? I want to make sure they're always logged

Comment: there is no level/logging involved, everything is written to the STDOUT and STDERR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the Django BaseCommand loggers and the logging logger?

**Yes**, a lot. `stdout` and `stderr` simply are I/O handlers that, by default, write to the [*standard output channel (stdout)* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and [*standard error channel (stderr)* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). These thus just write the content to these channels, and don't do any formatting, have no log level that might be ommited, and can not work with multiple handlers.

This is in essence what the logging package does: it allows one to format it properly, to omit it depending on the log level, and let it handle it by (multiple) custom handlers. For example to write it to the output channel, save it to a file, insert it in a database, etc.

> Does the Django BaseCommand logger use the logging module under the hood? If so, what level does `self.stdout` and `self.stderr` use?

**No**, the `logging` module has a handler that will, by default write to the output channel, although you can configure it to use a different handler.